# height: fit-content; not working by firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The dev tool tell me that the fit-content not working by Firefox. Can someone say what should I write instead fit-content.

```
.main--5 {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--firstColor);
  height: fit-content;
  opacity: 100 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
  display: block;
  display: none;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at *caniuse* website for CSS compatibility questions.
As explain [on this page](https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content), you can use **-moz-fit-content**.
You can also use
**display:flex**
on parent and **flex-grow:1** on child.